Deneb - scatterplot x & y sorted asc
I need to draw a scatterplot in DENEB (vega or vega lite).
Basically I need to create a scatter plot where I will have x and y sorted ascending and plot against each other, ... so the number are not correlated to each other anymore
Please have a look at the attached image
scatterplot
I tried but I cant sore x and y in the same time.
I guess I need to split this into two seperate lists, sort them and merge into one dataset???
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": "1", "y": "3.2"},
      {"x": "2", "y": "1.9"},
      {"x": "4", "y": "2.1"},
      {"x": "3", "y": "4.5"},
      {"x": "6", "y": "5.1"},
      {"x": "5", "y": "8.5"},
      {"x": "7", "y": "6"},
      {"x": "8", "y": "7.9"},
      {"x": "9", "y": "9.1"},
      {"x": "10", "y": "11"}
    ]
  },
    "mark": {"type":"line",
    "point":true},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
}


Please supply a spec with data. Thanks

Please create a scatter plot in which x and y are sorted ascending and independently.. Please check the image I attached. https://i.sstatic.net/DkEea24E.png

Where is your data and spec?

{
"data": {
"values": [
{"x": "1", "y": "3.2"},
{"x": "2", "y": "1.9"},
{"x": "4", "y": "2.1"},
{"x": "3", "y": "4.5"},
{"x": "6", "y": "5.1"},
{"x": "5", "y": "8.5"},
{"x": "7", "y": "6"},
{"x": "8", "y": "7.9"},
{"x": "9", "y": "9.1"},
{"x": "10", "y": "11"}
]
},
"mark": {"type":"line",
"point":true},
"encoding": {
"x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
"y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
}
}

You're best doing this upstream in Power Query.

My dataset is huge, around 500mln rows. Every additional column it's a lot of data

Yes but presumably you're not plotting 500m rows on a line chart? This is a data shaping exercise rather than a visualisation one. Why are your columns not linked anyway?

for sure must be a way to sort the data in vega...

Vega only solution.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "style": "cell",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {"x": 1, "y": 3.2},
        {"x": 2, "y": 1.9},
        {"x": 4, "y": 2.1},
        {"x": 3, "y": 4.5},
        {"x": 6, "y": 5.1},
        {"x": 5, "y": 8.5},
        {"x": 7, "y": 6},
        {"x": 8, "y": 7.9},
        {"x": 9, "y": 9.1},
        {"x": 10, "y": 11}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "params": [null],
          "as": ["row"],
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "fields": [null],
          "sort": {"field": [], "order": []}
        },
        {"type": "collect", "sort": {"field": "y"}}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "source_0",
      "transform": [
         {"type": "collect", "sort": {"field": "x"}},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "pluck(data('source_0'),'y')[datum.row-1]", "as": "newY"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_1",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "isValid(datum[\"x\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"x\"]) && isValid(datum[\"y\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"y\"])"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "layer_0_marks",
      "type": "line",
      "style": ["line"],
      "sort": {"field": "datum[\"x\"]"},
      "from": {"data": "data_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
          "description": {
            "signal": "\"x: \" + (format(datum[\"x\"], \"\")) + \"; y: \" + (format(datum[\"y\"], \"\"))"
          },
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "newY"},
          "defined": {
            "signal": "isValid(datum[\"x\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"x\"]) && isValid(datum[\"y\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"y\"])"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "layer_1_marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "style": ["point"],
      "from": {"data": "data_1"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "opacity": {"value": 1},
          "fill": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
          "ariaRoleDescription": {"value": "point"},
          "description": {
            "signal": "\"x: \" + (format(datum[\"x\"], \"\")) + \"; y: \" + (format(datum[\"y\"], \"\"))"
          },
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "newY"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_0", "field": "x"},
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "x"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": false
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_0", "field": "y"},
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "y"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "gridScale": "y",
      "grid": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "domain": false,
      "labels": false,
      "aria": false,
      "maxExtent": 0,
      "minExtent": 0,
      "ticks": false,
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "gridScale": "x",
      "grid": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "domain": false,
      "labels": false,
      "aria": false,
      "maxExtent": 0,
      "minExtent": 0,
      "ticks": false,
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "x",
      "labelFlush": true,
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "y",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "zindex": 0
    }
  ]
}


Sorry to bother you...
Can you please add reference line x=y?
Code blow doesn't work very well, especialy when numbers on x axis are much bigger than on y axis
{
"type": "rule",
"encode": {
"update": {
"x": {"value": 0},
"y": {
"field": {"group": "height"}
},
"x2": {
"field": {"group": "width"}
},
"y2": {"value": 0},
"stroke": {"value": "grey"},
"strokeWidth": {"value": 1}
}
}
}

Ask a new question with all the details necessary.
